# iPhone + UITableView with multiple columns

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to display a UITableView with Multiple Columns.

The first column will have some text and another column will have a button, click of button will navigate to some another view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar requirement; and did with the help of this..
http://dewpoint.snagdata.com/2008/10/31/drawing-a-grid-in-a-uitableview/

This would probably help you..