# Setting column header text for a UITableView in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How do I make a UITableView column header text, like a C#/.NET grid?

I make only records, but I can't set the UITableView column header text.
And I want proper formating in UITableView..

Comment: Please rephrase your question and include code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly I think you need this

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because a table view is not a .Net grid. If you want to have grid-like layout in your tableview, look at [iPhone Multiple Columns in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview) or [iPhone + UITableView with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629063/iphone-uitableview-with-multiple-columns)